# MSSQL Column Named Description In PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a DB with a field called Description, that is set as nvarchar(max). I am able to retrieve every other piece of data from the table, but not this one gets garbled every time.

```
$conn = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass, SQL_CUR_USE_DRIVER) or die('Failed to connect<br/>');
$test_rep = $conn->query('SELECT [Description] FROM InvoiceBase WHERE InvoiceNumber = \'652021\'');
$test_row = odbc_fetch_array($test_rep);
echo $test_row['Description'];
```

This gives me the output of:

```
D�D1ON�MN$1xNN
```

I believe this has to do the column name being a reserved word, but even using an alias name on that column gives me a similar result.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

**EDIT**

As per a suggestion, using:

```
echo utf8_decode($test_row['Description']);
```

Results in:

```
K?K1@O?N?$1?N?
```

**EDIT2**

Here is a portion of the create command on this table (I cut out 20 or so columns to save space, but left enough in there to give an idea of how this compares to other columns):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InvoiceBase](
    [InvoiceId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [OpportunityId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [PriorityCode] [int] NULL,
    [SalesOrderId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [OwningBusinessUnit] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [LastBackofficeSubmit] [datetime] NULL,
    [PriceLevelId] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [InvoiceNumber] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [DiscountAmount] [money] NULL,
    [FreightAmount] [money] NULL,
    [TotalAmount] [money] NULL,
    [CustomerIdYomiName] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [cndx_PrimaryKey_Invoice] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [InvoiceId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [AK1_InvoiceBase] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [OwningBusinessUnit] ASC,
    [InvoiceNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Looks to be an encoding issue, or a contributing one.

Comment: Try `echo utf8_decode($test_row['Description']);`

Comment: @RobertRozas - that outputs "K?K1@O?N?$1?N?" (The actual content of the field is english language)

Comment: What if you change the SQL to `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Description]) FROM InvoiceBase WHERE InvoiceNumber = \'652021\'` and let SQL handle the conversion between unicode/non-unicode?

Comment: @JiggsJedi that returns null/blank.

Comment: What if you try putting `$conn->set_charset("utf8");` right before your query?

Comment: Try `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,[Description]) as Description FROM InvoiceBase WHERE InvoiceNumber = \'652021\'`.. you're calling `Description` by name, the `CONVERT()` obfuscates that... so add an alias of `Description`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the name of the column. Looks like some kind of Unicode -> varchar -> utf translation problem.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand.. not sure if that was to me... but my original suggestion would remove the column name, so `echo $test_row['Description'];` could indeed return blank/null as that column wouldn't exist in the recordset.

Comment: @JiggsJedi No, that was for the OP. Changing the column name / alias to `description_2` or anything else that isn't "`description`" is not going to change the output (the title of the question certainly implies like that's the problem, and I can assure everyone it is not). However, now that I've looked at your comments, please [don't encourage people to use `convert` to `varchar` without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @Fred-ii- that returns null/blank as well.

Comment: Take PHP out of the picture for a moment. How does the output look when you run the same query in Management Studio? What is the collation of the column? And of course, what are the UTF settings of your PHP files?

Comment: @AaronBertrand in Management Studio it returns "they need ASAP please send 2nd DAY AIR forward tracking for order thanks"

Comment: Okay, so it looks right in Management Studio. So now look at your PHP files... do they have things like charset/utf? What editor did you use to create them? What are its default settings for saving files?

Comment: @AaronBertrand this is actually building an HTML string that then gets sent out using mail(). All of the other fields on the invoice display just fine, it's just this one particular field that is off. There's probably 25-30 fields from the same table that display correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56150/discussion-between-cory-dee-and-aaron-bertrand).

Comment: So what is different about this column? What are the definitions of the other columns? Can you script out the `CREATE TABLE` and add that information to the question? You should always start with as much information as possible, rather than make people pull teeth to get this information. Simplifying might seem better to you, but it's not better for anyone trying to help you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand the only difference between this field, and the Name field (which displays correctly) is that Name is defined length (nvarchar(300)), and description is max length (nvarchar(max))